# tcl expression to rename multiple strings in a file

Tags: string, scripting, tcl

In a file, I have multiple strings,

```
valid_packet,
rst_int_reg,
write_enb,
enb_read,
state_lfd, ...
```

I have to rename the strings in the below format

```
validpacket
lfd_state
read_enb
```

I have written an expression to rename a few of the strings

```
set signals " valid_packet, rst_int_reg, write_enb, read_enb, state_lfd, ..."

set signals [regsub "valid_packet" $signals "validpacket"]
set signals [regsub "enb_read" $signals "read_enb"]
set signals [regsub "state_lfd" $signals "lfd_state"]
puts $signals
```

For each string, I had to write the same expression, so is there any optimized way, because if I have to rename many strings in a file, I need to repeat the same expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be better done with [`string map`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34) which can convert many different words throughout a text in one go, though you'll still have to write out what you're changing from and to as there doesn't seem to be a general pattern (in a regular-expression sense at least).

```
set signals " valid_packet, rst_int_reg, write_enb, read_enb, state_lfd, ..."

# This is a list of changes to do, but I like to put each transform on its own line
set mapping {
    "valid_packet" "validpacket"
    "enb_read" "read_enb"
    "state_lfd" "lfd_state"
}

# Apply the mapping
set signals [string map $mapping $signals]
puts $signals
```

Comment: What happens is that `string map` considers, in order, at each character, which transform it can apply; if one does, it consumes those characters and emits the transformation target, and if none does then it leaves the character alone. It's a really simple algorithm, and it works unreasonably well, as we've tried to optimise it a few times and never did better in reality…